# Css Refuses to display image?

Tags: html, css

I've tried displaying an image like this in every possible way I can think of:
1. links to a website like it is now
2. having the image be local: bird.png
3. i always double check the name of the image is right and the extension
4. ../images/bird.png
etc.
Any help is appreciated

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title> Internal Affairs Inc. | When Information Really Matters </title>

    <style>
        #logo
        {
            background-image:url('http://www.birds.com/wp-content/uploads/home/bird4.jpg');   
        }

    </style>

</head>
    <h1>ho</h1>
<body>
    <div id="logo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the `<div>` have any height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div doesn't have any dimensions. 0 height. Add some height of `302px` as the image is 302px high:

```css
#logo {
  background-image:url('http://www.birds.com/wp-content/uploads/home/bird4.jpg');
  height: 302px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo"></div>
```

Comment: @ChandlerCoates Don't forget the accept button! `:)`

Comment: that works, stack overflow says i have to wait 8 minutes to accept your answer

Comment: @ChandlerCoates Yes yes, after 8 mins.

Answer (score 0):

Your div has no dimensions, so is 0x0 and a bg image is not visible.  Try:

```
#logo
    {
        background-image:url('http://www.birds.com/wp-content/uploads/home/bird4.jpg');
        width: 592px;
        height: 302px;
    }
```

Comment: Not 0x0. It's 0x100%

Comment: It’s not 0×0, it only has 0 height.